# Why doesn't Mathematica recognise two integrals as equal?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

The following expression
$$\int_{0}^{t} f(t_0) \,dt_0 - \int_{0}^{t} f(t_1) \,dt_1 = 0$$
is zero because it is just a change of integration variable.

Why doesn't Mathematica give zero in this case?

```
Integrate[f[t1],{t1,0,t}]-Integrate[f[t2],{t2,0,t}]
```

Comment: Maple gives zero `simplify(int(f(t1),t1=0..t)-int(f(t2),t2=0..t))` gives zero. So I think you are right, Mathematica should give zero. I tried both Simplify and FullSimplify.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoEFe.png)  may be there a trick to make it simplify it to zero

Comment: Mathematically it is zero, I believe the logic just hasn't been implemented in mathematica

Comment: You have to define what your f[x] is. Not all functions can be integrated, for example, Tan[x] is infinite when x=pi/2

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is zero Mathematically, the question is if there a trick to make or help Mathematica see that.  Sometimes computers are not as smart as we think they are :)

Comment: any way to do it and keep f undefined?

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate why you are interested in this? Are you just interested in the reasons behind it, or do you have an actual application where you want to use this? For very simple cases (!!), you could do some hacky things like: `canonicalizeIntVars[expr_] := With[{tnew = Unique[t]}, expr /. Integrate[f_, {t_, t1_, t2_}] :> Integrate[f /. t -> tnew, {tnew, t1, t2}]]` which will make all integrals have the same integration variable. Then `Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, t}] - Integrate[f[t2], {t2, 0, t}] // canonicalizeIntVars` gives 0.

Comment: I have an application with many nested integrals, and this behaviour is just a prerequisite  so that I can calculate some results in high order perturbation theory.

Comment: I agree. Mathematica understands many symbolic relations. The fact that an integral shouldn't depend on the name of the dummy variable should be fairly easy to spot.

Comment: I don't know much about that, but is there a particular reason why you need different variable names in the integrals?

Comment: Yeah I mean I will have large calculations with many terms I wont even know what's in them. I would expect mathematica to have this very basic behaviour otherwise my calculation will not be reliable

Answer (score 5):

You have to tell what your function is. Mathematica cannot output undefined values, for example, the integral result is infinite in some interval.

```
f[x_] := Tan[x];
Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, \[Pi]/2}] - Integrate[f[t2], {t2, 0, \[Pi]/2}]
```

And

```
f[x_] := Tan[x];
Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, \[Pi]/3}] - Integrate[f[t2], {t2, 0, \[Pi]/3}]
```

You can compare the 2 results.

Comment: *"You have to tell what your function is. Mathematica cannot output undefined values"*... this doesn't sound right? It can clearly turn `f(x) - f(x)` into `0` despite everything being undefined in that expression.

Comment: I believe here Mathematica is correct and Maple is wrong - if `f` were a function such that the integral is infinite, the difference should be indeterminate, not zero. So one cannot just simplify it to zero without assuming the integral is finite.

Answer (score 5):

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, t}] - Integrate[f[t2], {t2, 0, t}], 
 Assumptions -> t1 == t2]

(* 0 *)
```

Or if you encounter such situation mentioned in @Domen's comment:

```
expr = Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, t}] - Integrate[f[t2], {t2, 0, t}] + 
   t1 - t2;

expr /. Integrate[x_, {y_, z_, q_}] :> 
  Integrate[x /. y -> uniquename, {uniquename, z, q}]

(* t1 - t2 *)
```

Comment: Just a note, one has to be quite careful here because this doesn't take into account the correct local scoping of integration variables. Namely, `FullSimplify[Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, t}] - Integrate[f[t2], {t2, 0, t}] + t1 - t2, Assumptions -> t1 == t2]` will give 0 instead of `t1 - t2`.

Answer (score 0):

This  can be grounded in such a way (of course, assuming the existence of the integral `Integrate][f[t2], {t2, 0, t}]`):

```
Activate[IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][f[t2], {t2, 0, t}], t1, t1 == t2]]
```

> `Integrate[f[t1], {t1, 0, t}]`